# gzip with split - is there a way to figure out when split file is complete?

Tags: linux, bash, gzip

I'm running a gzip command from a bash script, it looks something like this:

```
 gzip -cr /source | split -b 1024m - /backup/03-31-16_backup.gz
```

Is there any way I can know when a chunked file is complete (ie. 03-31-16_backup.gzaa, 03-31-16_backup.gzab, etc)? I know I could technically just check the size and see if its 1024m but the last file in this process probably wouldn't meet this criteria.

I couldn't find a verbose option for `split` so I can't capture the output & gzip doesn't tell me much either.

Basically I want to be able to upload the completed split files while gzip is still working since it takes quite a long time to complete. I can't pipe it, the API I'm using doesn't support that.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: The file size check will work for all but the last file. You can process the last file as a special case after `gzip` is finished.

Comment: You could likely try to parse `lsof` to see if anything is still holding an open handle to the file. If you do that, definitely do some testing to see if `split` actually closes the handle to the file etc...

Comment: @JoelC, yes it does close the handle. The `lsof` suggestion worked well. Thanks